# POST request through iOS

Tags: ios, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

So i've set up a POST request sending information about a user's name, email and password along with an image. The page im sending a request to has been coded to `var_dump($_FILES)`, `var_dump($_POST)` and this information is returned and logged. However, the `var_dump()` shows that it has not received a file or any `POST` data. The error I am assuming must be in the way the POST request has been coded, however I can't see what the error is:

```
    NSString *name = self.step1view.name.text;
    NSString *email = self.step2view.email.text;
    NSString *password = self.step3view.password2.text;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"name: %@; email: %@; password: %@",name,email,password]);
    //create URL
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    //Create post request connection
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"ghkyre–nhjfhdj-74f5f-gfg5-gggff";

    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

    [postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

    //USERNAME
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //EMAIL
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",email] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //PASSWORD
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //IMAGE
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

    //send request
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response: %@",returnString);
```

Comment: Use a network analyzer (sniffer) like Charles Proxy (free trial) to actually see what is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. When setting the `Content-Type`header, use `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField` rather than `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField`.
2. There's a superfluous CRLF for the image parameter:

   This:

   ```
   [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   should be

   ```
   [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```
3. Don't pass `nil` to `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error` for either the `response` or `error` parameters. Both of these will hold vital debugging information after the request has been made.

**UPDATE:** Your boundary `ghkyre–nhjfhdj-74f5f-gfg5-gggff` contains a Unicode character `–`. Replace it with `-` and you can access the POST data via PHP.

Comment: I changed both of those however with no avail unfortunately. The php page still receives no POST data

Comment: That was it! The unicode character was the problem. Thank you!